# how to extract value from Array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Let just say i have this `[{"id":21},{"id":22}]` array coming up from this :

```
$schedules = [];
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $schedules[] =Schedule::select('id')
                        ->whereIn('route_id', $route)
                        ->latest()
                        ->first();  
    }
```

So, i want to extract the value from it like this `[21,22]`, so i did it like this:

```
$values = $schedules->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

this showing this error

> Call to a member function pluck() on array

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want to extract the values from `[{"id":21},{"id":22}]` like this `[21,22]` @ZeshanKhattak

Comment: I take it you're getting an error??

Comment: Why do you want to use **any** OOP method on a raw array? If you want to extract the first item of an array, use `array_pop` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you're after with the code you have you can use `array_map`:

```
$values = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item->id;
}, $schedules);
```

Alternatively, you could simply get the `id` initially by either using `->first()->id` or `value('id')`:

```
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    $schedules[] =Schedule::select('id')
                    ->whereIn('route_id', $route)
                    ->latest()
                    ->value('id');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first make a collection of it first and then use `pluck`.

I assume you have the following data

```php
$schedules = [
    ["id" => 21],
    ["id" => 22]
];
```

```php
return collect($schedules)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

[Demo here](https://implode.io/Ly5OiH)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get just the values.

```
$values = array_column($schedules->pluck('id')->toArray(),'id');
```

Comment: i think that's not working and it's showing this`Call to a member function pluck() on array`

Comment: @Lafoune In that case your `$schedules->pluck('id')->toArray()` itself is not working.  Are you sure it works? What does `dd($schedules)` give you?

Comment: thanks man for your quick responce but some of our friend some how got it right, btw thanks pal